# Speaker on iPhone not working with Skype or Viber

Tags: iphone, applications, skype, ios

I have an iPhone 4, a couple of days ago the speaker when using Skype and Viber stopped working, I tried removing the apps and reinstalling them and have updated to 5.0.1 and it is still not working. I can still hear normal calls but for some reason when making Viber and Skype calls I can't hear, only the other person can hear me.

What else can I do?

Comment: I have exact same problem on skype and viber. The thing is that you can hear through speakerphone BUT not through earpiece. It is really weird. Is there any solution or info about this issue?

Comment: This is not device specific. I am experiencing the same problem. Viber, Skype, Fring only able to hear through speaker and not ear-piece. I can use a bluetooth and it will work fine.
Wierd
As it appears to apply to all VOIP software, it would appear that Apple have the answer.

Comment: no its not a device specific i have the iphone 4s and i am experiancing the exact same problem, it started when i started using the headphones, suddenly the earpieace just stopped working with viber, skype and all other voip apps.
and it most probabaly a software problem with the new version of ios 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

This is a member of the Viber Development Team! :)

Please see our Help Desk at: http://helpme.viber.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/25/0/iphone-viber-connection-issues  for information concerning connection and audio issues.

If the issue persists it might be related to your own specific device. (You can contact Apple support).

If you have any question about Viber - please feel free to ask.

Thank you, 
Viber Team.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.